# angular ts: Parse a json into object of specific type

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have json string like this

```
{"Response": 
 [
{"Amount": 0, 
 "Date": "23/1/15", 
 "Id": 12379}, 
{"Amount": 0,  
 "Id": 123}
]
}
```

and want to convert it in single object of type

```
class myobject
{
  int Amount;
  String Date;
  int Id;
  String name;
}
```

If values are not provided in json string consider them null
If JSON.parse is used it will parse it into two different objects

How to parse it in object of specific type?

Answer (score 0):

You can use interface with optional properties adding `?` after the property name.

```
interface MyObject
{
   Amount?: number;
   Date?: string;
   Id?: number;
   Name?: string;
}
```

Check the example in the [**TS Playground**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20MyObject%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Amount%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Date%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Id%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Name%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20json%20%3D%20%60%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Amount%22%3A%200%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Date%22%3A%20%2223%2F1%2F15%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Id%22%3A%2012379%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Amount%22%3A%200%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Id%22%3A%20123%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%60%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20data%20%3D%20JSON.parse(json)%20as%20MyObject%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(data%5B0%5D.Id)%3B).